# HP pavillion DV7-3065DX Cannot boot

Tags: windows-7, system-restore

I did a system restore and the computer powered out during the restore. The computer will turn on but windows keeps trying to start and stops and then tries again and again and again, but no go.

Please advise and thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You could do a repair install using the original installation disk (you'll need the product activation code from the box). Insert the CD, boot from the the CD, follow the screens to repair the windows installation on your computer.

Alternatively,

Method 1: Choose the Same or Another Restore Point to do a system restore.

1. Start System Restore.
2. Click Restore my computer to an earlier time, and then click Next.
3. Choose a restore point from the System Restore Calendar in the Select a Restore Point dialog box, and then click Next.

Method 2: Undo the Previous Restoration

1. Start System Restore.
2. Click Undo my last restoration, and then click Next.

HTH!